# Can't set opacity of router-outlet for animations [Chrome]

Tags: css, angular, google-chrome

I have a single page Angular 4.3.1 app that uses the `<router-outlet>` tag to render components.

The issue is that the component is rendered with an encapsulating element called: `<ng-component>` (if no selector is present).

So the issue is when I apply **opacity** to the wrapper the child elements are not effected. It seems as if it's because the wrapper is a custom DOM element.

Here is an example

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <ng-component style="opacity: 0.2;">
    <div>First Line</div>
    <div>Second Line</div>
    <div>Third Line</div>
  </ng-component>

  <div style="opacity: 0.2;">
    <div>First Line</div>
    <div>Second Line</div>
    <div>Third Line</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I'm using chrome version 59.0.3071.115 which seems to be the latest version right now.

Also here is a screenshot in case the problem is only on my end:

[image: Opacity]

I tested the same thing in IE11 but the opacity was fine there. Anyone else experiencing this?

### Update

Upon request, here is the angular routing animation I'm trying to get working on Chrome:

```
export const routerAnimation =
    trigger('routerAnimation', [
        transition(':enter', [

            // styles at start of transition
            style({ opacity: 0 }),

            // animation and styles at end of transition
            animate('0.3s', style({ opacity: 1 }))
        ]),
    ])

@Component({
    selector: '...',
    templateUrl: '...',
    styleUrls: ['...'],
    animations: [routerAnimation],
    host: { '[@routerAnimation]': '' }
})
```

Comment: If this is indeed an issue experienced by others, any workarounds would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You can nest a `<style></style>` block inside `<ng-component></ng-component>`. In your case:

```
<style>
    ng-component > div {opacity: 0.2;}
</style>
```

Here's the full snippet:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <ng-component>
  
      <style>
        ng-component > div {opacity: 0.2;}
      </style>      
  
      <div>First Line</div>
      <div>Second Line</div>
      <div>Third Line</div>
  </ng-component>

  <div style="opacity: 0.2;">
    <div>First Line</div>
    <div>Second Line</div>
    <div>Third Line</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

It works on my version of Chrome (Version 59.0.3071.115)

Comment: So is this normal behavior? This method doesn't really help me do my Angular4 animations.

Comment: Added it to my question

Comment: add this property `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` to your component's object and tell me if that works for you.

Comment: I do need my ViewEncapsulation though. I also added how I'm applying the animation to my component: I'm using the **host** field. Is there another way I can apply the animation to my component without adding the necessary classes to the **ng-component** element?

Comment: I can't test it myself but can you try styling your component with the selector `:host` by adding `:host { opacity:0.2 }` in your CSS file

Comment: Well I don't actually have any css anywhere. The animation trigger applies the *opacity* to the element directly. I'll create a testable angular plunker

Comment: @LiamHealy no problem happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

Another way, without need any manually changes in the body tag of your question.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
  $(function(){
     $('ng-component').each(function(){$(this).children().attr('style',$(this).attr('style'));});
   });
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <ng-component style="opacity: 0.2;">
    <div>First Line</div>
    <div>Second Line</div>
    <div>Third Line</div>
  </ng-component>
</body>
</html>
```

> I implement it by `jQuery` but if you do not want using `jQuery` in your project you can rewrite it by `JavaScript`.